# Permission Denied when opening logs in minikube Nodes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

When I am trying to access my logs inside minikube folder I am getting this permission denied error.

```
docker@minikube:/var/log/containers$ cat ltservice-68d7dd45b4-kbk8j_default_ltservice-2bb5839b63233ee0ccf4cbdb72aba361890e2efa0995bbfb2ddd0b3cd20eb331.log
cat: ltservice-68d7dd45b4-kbk8j_default_ltservice-2bb5839b63233ee0ccf4cbdb72aba361890e2efa0995bbfb2ddd0b3cd20eb331.log: Permission denied
```

I can access my logs using Kubectl logs podname. Wondering what I need to change inside minikube node to read the logs directly from /var/log/containers folder

```
  ps -eaf |grep minikube
  501 57526 57508   0 10:44am ttys001    0:00.32 minikube ssh
  501 57876 57859   0 11:01am ttys003    0:00.00 grep minikube



ls -lrt ltservice-554c44d977-mtz4w_default_ltservice-d69c635fa717d8e1abf4bb9ef2cebf7379d4abfd791c235b7c51f7f14d6dde5f.log

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 103 May  6 17:51 ltservice-554c44d977-mtz4w_default_ltservice-d69c635fa717d8e1abf4bb9ef2cebf7379d4abfd791c235b7c51f7f14d6dde5f.log -> /var/log/pods/default_ltservice-554c44d977-mtz4w_adb176bb-038b-4f32-a2a8-8a30dc448d60/ltservice/110.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run as root or with root privileges, you can create a user and add it to the sudo group if the sudo command doesn't work.